# Fullcalendar with Django does not save events

Tags: javascript, django, fullcalendar

I connected the fullcalendar to my django project and now when I save events from the month view, everything works, but as soon as I switch to the day or week display, the events are not saved to the database. However, there are no errors.

**fullcalendar script**

```
       <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
              var clickDate = date.format();
              $('#start-date').val(clickDate);
              $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            },                        
            eventSources: [

    {
      events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

                },
                {% endfor %}

            ],
    }    
  ]
        });
        //add new event
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'drop',
        duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'clip',
        duration: 500
    }
});
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    });

</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def event(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        event_form = ModelEventsForm(request.POST)
        if event_form.is_valid():
            update = event_form.save(commit=False)
            update.owner = request.user.profile
            update.start_date = event_form.cleaned_data['start_date']    
            update.save()
        return redirect('events:event')
    else:
        event_form = ModelEventsForm()
    context = {
        "events": all_events,
        'event_form': event_form
    }
    return render(request, 'profile/event_management.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Events(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ModelEventsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        exclude = ['event_type', 'owner']
```

**template forms**

```
 <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="event_name">Name</label>
              {%  render_field  event_form.event_name class="form-control" id='event_name' %}

          </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="start-date">НStart</label>
              {%  render_field  event_form.start_date class="form-control datepicker" id='start-date' %}

          </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="end-date">End</label>
                 {%  render_field  event_form.end_date class="form-control datepicker" id='end-date' %}

          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New event</button>
        </form>
```

If create an event for the whole day, then in the console I can see that the date is 2018-12-12 00: 00: 00 + 03: 00. If create an event that contains time, then the data does not come to the server.

Comment: you haven't shown the code by which you transmit the data to the server...so it's a little hard to help. But I would guess you aren't sending it in a format which the server can understand.

Comment: @ADyson I send data to the server using  **views.py**

Comment: No, views.py itself runs on the web server. It doesn't _send_ anything to the server, it _is_ the server. You must have used a form or some JavaScript code to send it from the browser to the server before that.

Comment: @ADyson I update my question, maybe you mean **template form**

Comment: ok thanks, yes that's what I meant. So basically that confirms to me that you are just submitting the date to the server including a time, exactly as `date.format()` outputs it. And for some reason the server does not like that - is it programmed only to expect dates in a specific format? The code you've shown doesn't tell me how the python code is validating or processing the data. Also have you debugged the python to see if it generates any errors or exceptions? Or maybe it's an error at the database level? Just saying it doesn't insert the data indicates you haven't done much investigation.